# Did Taiga come back to stay or was she just visiting?

Tags: toradora

In the very last episode of *Toradora*, after the credits, Taiga comes back. Did she come back to stay or was she just visiting?

Answer (score 2):

It's unspecific what happens afterwards in the anime.  Given that this is Ryuuji's graduation, and he and Taiga were in the same class year, it'd be implied that they're both graduating high school at this point.  If she were to "stay", that would imply that they're either moving in together or something else, which is *also* unspecified.

If nothing else, what we can say is that she is definitely visiting, but even the length of her visit is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

They are getting married, It is folly to assume that she is doing anything other then staying. Though what happens next is unknown it is safe to assume they are facing this unknown together.

Comment: When is it stated that they're getting married?

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your answer.